# Why doesn't this little function multiplier work

Tags: python

```
def do_twice(f,x):
    f(x)
    f(x)

def do_four(f,x):
    do_twice(do_twice(f,x),x)

def printx(x):
    print(x)

do_four(printx,"text")
```

I am a beginner to the language and I found that functions can be sent as a parameter easily. So I decided to work with it. But I tried this, and some randomly changed versions of it, which all failed.

```
def do_four(f,x):
    do_twice(f,x)
    do_twice(f,x)
```

I know that I can solve the problem like that, but since the one before doesn't work, I wanted to know why.

Comment: How did it "fail"? Please elaborate on the behavior you are expecting, and the behavior you are seeing, and how it isn't adequate. Are you getting an error? Then post the full error message including stack trace.

Comment: nice experiment! Does it work if you (just for troubleshooting) define `do_twice1(f,x)` and `do_twice2(f,x)` and then call `do_twice1(do_twice2(printx,'text'),'text')`? My thought is, that maybe one must not call a function from within itself. E.g. the interpreter also does not allow you to import modules recursively

Comment: You are passing `do_twice(f,x)` wrong in this line `do_twice(do_twice(f,x),x)`. First parameter of `do_twice` is a function reference, not a function call (`None` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Your nested call to `do_twice()` (inside `do_four()`) returns `None` because you didn't explicitly return something else. The "outer" call to `do_twice()` then sees the value `None` as the function to call, but `None` is not a function.

The innermost function call to `do_twice()` is evaluated first in order to establish the first argument to the outer call. This innermost call passes the correct arguments (a function and an object). This results in the first two printed lines of `text`. When the first invocation of `do_twice()` returns, it returns `None` which is the default return if an explicit return is not given.

`None` then is passed as the first argument to the outermost invocation of `do_twice()`, but `None` is not a function, so you cannot "call" it. Ultimately, the outer call will appear to be an invocation like the following:

```
do_twice(None, x)
       # ^^^^ note the None value here; None is not a function, so
       #      the subsequent call to do_twice() fails
```

If `do_twice()` checked to see if `f` is a function before trying to call `f`, this error would not occur and instead you would just see the two lines of `text` printed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your four function:

```
def do_four(f,x):
    do_twice(do_twice(f,x),x)
```

The  first call to `do_twice` will run as the inputs are correct, but since that **`call` will return `None`**, the next call to `do_twice` tries to call the function  "`None`" and thus fails.

---

So, you have two options, you can either just do the call twice explicitly:

```
def do_four(f,x):
    do_twice(f,x)
    do_twice(f,x)
```

or use a `for-loop` which is more *scalable*:

```
def do_four(f,x):
    for _ in range(2):
        do_twice(f, x)
```